# Transmission clunk & car shake (stationary, on cold start, switching into gear)?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, xterra

Vehicle 2004 1st gen Xterra, automatic transmission.

My transmission is making an audible 'thud' or 'clunk' and making the whole car shake when switching from P to R, from R to D and back, etc (basically shifting gears while stationary). Only does this when the car is cold (after sitting overnight). After the car is driven even a bit and the engine is up to operating temp, seems to shift just fine. Only noticed this the last few days - one thing to note is that it's been cold outside (-10c). Having said that, I I don't remember it doing this last winter.

Does anyone else experience this in the winter? Wondering if this is normal for automatic transmissions?? I'd imagine that with cold weather, the tranny fluid is more viscous - which explains why shifting gets better once the car is warm/driving.

I did flush the tranny fluid last year with synthetic. Vehicle only has 180,000km...

A few things I can think of:
- Somehow some moisture got into the tranny oil and it's freezing and causing harsh shifting?
- When the tranny is cold all the metal parts shrink so I'd imagine you'd get worse tolerances so might have some internal leaks in the fluid? Wondering if this is a sign that my tranny is on the way out?

Any ideas?

Comment: First thing to check is universal joints. These are easy to diagnose by a mechanic and not a wallet buster.

Comment: Is the engine revving higher than it should be when it is cold?

Comment: I would imagine the u-joints wouldn't be effected by temperature, so the clunk would be there even after the engine warmed up, no?

Comment: @HandyHowie no, revs are to spec and haven't changed. Why do you ask?

Comment: If the revs are high when a gear is selected you can get a thud and if the engine mounts are weak it could cause the engine to move considerably.

Comment: @HandyHowie actually, I take that back - the revs are higher! I think warm engine is supposed to rev around 800rpm, but on cold start the truck was revving at 1500rpm. I'm guessing this is causing the clunk as you say. 

It's interesting that the clunk/shake reduced significantly even after just 1min of having the truck in gear. The revs did go down a bit, to 1100rpm when this happened, but still not the 800 I usually see at warm-idle.

Comment: The thud is strong enough to make the car shake?  Anyway sounds like "tranny on its way out" to me, try some of the various transmission fluid additives and see if they help?